# Manually set exposure for iOS camera in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4, avcapture, exposure

How can I set Aperture and how it will effect in image?
I have managed ISO and shutter speed.but I am not able to set Aperture value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Aperture is a fixed mechanical size and cannot be changed - neither through code nor device settings.

You can ***get*** the aperture (the size of the lens diaphragm) via the `AVCaptureDevice` `.lensAperture` property, but you cannot change it.

Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624589-lensaperture

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.You have any written document by apple for it?If it is there Please Share it.

Comment: While I have not been able to find any specific statement on Apple's site regarding the (mechanical) non-adjustable Aperture, there are plenty of site that mention it. I added a link in my answer to Apple Docs where it states: ***This value does not change.***